# Restricting Entry to only digits and a full stop in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an entry which I restricted to only digits (it cannot accept any other symbol or letter), now I want it to accept only full stop (.)

Here is the code which restricts entry to only digits.

```
private static void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.NewTextValue))
        {
            bool isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray().All(x => char.IsDigit(x)); //Make sure all characters are numbers

            ((Entry)sender).Text = isValid ? args.NewTextValue : args.NewTextValue.Remove(args.NewTextValue.Length - 1);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray().All(x => char.IsDigit(x) || x.Equals('.'));
```

Comment: How did i miss that!! Thanks.. :)